# Firebase Query Duplication

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running a query on my DB and I know that there are going to be duplicated records, is there a way to avoid getting those duplications on the payload of the function? I know I can filter it after but I'm paying for those duplications right? Plus, since I only want 10, if there are 9 duplications, that means I only get 1 product.

Here is what I have:

```
getTopSell(city: string) {
    return this.db.collection('products/', ref => ref.where('city', '==', city).limit(10).orderBy('numLikes'))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(snaps => {
                return snaps.map(
                    snap => {
                        return { id: snap.payload.doc.id, ...snap.payload.doc.data() } as Product;
                    }
                );
            })
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have a way to query for documents that are in some way like or unlike other documents in the database.  Or, to put it another way, there are no SQL-like join type queries.  The only types of queries are those that filter and order documents from a single collection, or from a "collection group".  The filtering can only occur using specific values that you provide from the client app - they can't come from the values of other documents that haven't been read yet.

Unfortunately, the only way to do this is by checking for duplicates in the client.

Comment: Hey @Doug thank you. I suspected that but wanted to be sure. Thank you!